# External port forwarding stop working when VPN is activated

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding, lan

I've a problem with my local Debian server.

I use a port forward to allow access from outside my lan to my server. It's works very well but when I activate my VPN (OpenVPN) on my server, the port redirection stop working.
I still can access to my server in my lan but from outside nothing still work.

I don't understand why my redirection stop working, do you have some clues ?

Comment: Default route was changed, check your routing table.

Comment: You mean your server uses OpenVPN as a client or you are starting the OpenVPN server and it fails? Assuming you mean the client scenario: compare the output of `route` or `ip route` before and after connecting the VPN. Also, routing can be done at the firewall level, too. So `iptables-save` or `ip6tables-save` output should be compared accordingly.